# VB.net - Datagridview Hide password

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

I'm trying to **** out the password column in my Datagrid. I've managed to do it for the correct cell. Now i would like to see the password for a row when i click it.

Is this possible?

```
Private Sub dgvData_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles dgvData.CellFormatting
    If e.RowIndex > dgvData.Rows.Count() _
        OrElse e.RowIndex < 0 _
        OrElse dgvData.Rows(e.RowIndex) Is Nothing _
        OrElse dgvData.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataBoundItem Is Nothing Then
        e.Value = Nothing
    ElseIf e.ColumnIndex = 4 Then
        e.Value = "*********"
    End If
End Sub
```

Any Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: the code in the question is about the formatting: to show the password you should handle a different event, maybe CellClick or something related to rows selection.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I tried a cell click event but i can't seem to undo the formatting?

Comment: in your code you didn't format the data but overwrite it so you can't 'undo formatting' because you didn't format anything. read the data once more and output the data instead of overwriting it with '*********'

Comment: I've tried doing that with a cellclick event, but it doesn't undo the ******** I tried to fill the datagrid again but obviously it calls the cellformat once it's populated. Excuse my noobness!